# How can I access another domain's cookies from a Silverlight app?

Tags: silverlight, cookies, cross-domain

I have two different webpages. The first is a php app that creates a cookie (http://www.phpapp.com). The second is a silverlight app (http://www.silverlightapp.com).

The question is how could I access to cookie that is created by php app from the silverlight app hosted on the second website?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, explain your scenario as this might help suggesting you a way out of your situation. Do you need to pass data from one app to the other? Do you need a form of OpenID? Why do you need what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it's impossible due to security restrictions - a browser won't allow a site to access cookies from another domain. Check out:

- [Cross-Domain Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies)
- [Silverlight not sending cookies in cross-domain browser requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072480/silverlight-not-sending-cookies-in-cross-domain-browser-requests)

The first link also gives some workarounds.

Comment: I reached to the same conclusion. Thanks for your reply!